# Parâmetros passados para um web service - Asp .Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-service

Meu problema é o seguinte, estou fazendo um app no Xamarin Forms e tenho que enviar dois parâmetros para um web service desenvolvido no Asp .Net MVC, no caso eu gostaria de saber como posso enviar esses parâmetros(duas strings) via URL apenas para testar e ver se o WEB Service esta retornando o resultado esperado.
Por exemplo: http://meuwebservice.com/api/controleChamado/"???????????", quero saber o que posso colocar no lugar das interrogações. Desde já agradeço a quem puder ajudar.

Atenciosamente,

Comment: Oi Diego, obrigado por responder. Então, eu configurei a action para receber dois parâmetros do tipo string, param1 e param2. Eu tenho uma outra action que recebe apenas um parâmetro e eu passo ele normal, como você falou : http://url/api/nomedaaction/parametro e o server me retorna a busca. Porém, eu não sei como passar dois parametros de uma vez, exemplo : http://url/api/minhaaction/"parametro1&parametro2". No caso vou ter que configurar a aplicação para receber esses parâmetros concatenados? agradeço novamente.

Comment: Você pode [usar o atributo `Route`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26744056/8093394), se for um padrão, pode também [definir como rota global](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16553781/8093394) ou ainda passar os parâmetros na própria url, seria algo como `http://endereco.com/api/controleChamado?id=2&idPai=15&outroparam=valor`...